# How to update mac OS application to support Catalina?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos

I have an old mac OS application developed in Mojave with the deployment target 10.12. Now how to update mac OS application to support Catalina? Or is the application automatically supports all future mac OS versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When developing for macOS *(or any other Apple platform, for that matter)*, there are two key concepts to take into account when thinking about compatibility:

- The SDK version: this is the SDK you're compiling against and it is usually determined by the Xcode version you're using to build your project.
- The Deployment Target: this is the lowest OS version you want to support.

Normally, if you have followed the best practice in implementing your code and all of your dependencies have done the same, updating an app for a new macOS version requires only to download the latest Xcode on the latest macOS, build it and run your smoke tests (manually or through [automated tests](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/user_interface_tests)).

There may be things that have been deprecated in the meantime and Xcode will report them as warnings while building. You may read more about deprecated APIs in the [macOS 10.15 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes).

Keep in mind that you don't actually have to rebuild your app every time a new macOS version comes out. Even though it is better to test it at least once and dedicate time to explore and make use of new APIs, apps built on the previous version of macOS will, **most of the times**, run flawlessly on the next version (and maybe even further). This obviously depends on the app complexity, so your mileage may vary.